# Regex to detect url containing other urls

Tags: c#, php, regex, perl

> XXXXXXhttp://something/something-http://directedto.com/XXXXXXX

I have a list of strings like that where X stands for a random extended ASCII character. I can't find any web source of regex that help me to get

> http://something/something-http://directedto.com/

out of the string. Could you provide me a regex pattern that really helps ?

EDIT; the above string is just an example.
as other cases e.g

> XXXXXhttp://something/somehttp/qausiehfiuhakjh-/http://directedto.net/soemthignelseXXXXXXX
>   XXXXXXXXXXhttp://www.yahoo.com/_ylt=Asq0NTMqTVFcCmnB3eR857SbvZx4;_ylu=X3oDMTNvZ2dtNnI1BGEDMQRjY29kZQNwemJ1YWxsY2FoNQRjcG9zAzIEZwMxBGludGwDdXMEbWNvZGUDcHpidWFsbGNhaDUEbXBvcwMzBHBrZ3QDMgRwb3MDMQRzZWMDdGQtbG9jBHNsawN0aXRsZQR0ZXN0AzcwMQR3b2UDMjQ1OTExNQ--/SIG=14l1h2t2v/EXP=1322779228/**http://www.nytimes.com/2011/12/01/nyregion/told-to-diversify-dock-union-offers-nearly-all-white-list.html%3Fsrc=me%26ref=nyregionXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Comment: So in your second example, you want the code to detect that `www.yahoo.com` is a url, even though it doesn't start with `http`? What if it was `example.tv`, or something like that? Do you guarantee that the embedded url starts with `http://` or `https://`? You need to define your problem much more tightly.

Comment: Yes, I edit it again., I only try to do a string extraction with regex patterm

Answer (score 1):

Detecting a URL is actually very difficult, because it can contain almost any character including "random extended ascii" ones. A good explanation of why it's so hard is here: http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls. Unfortunately that example assumes there is some kind of "word boundary" around the URL, which is not the case for your problem.

There isn't any way to reliably detect any possible url, but you could make some assumptions, perhaps your urls all start with 'http:' or 'https:' and only contain alpha-numeric characters, underscores and periods? This would work for that:

```
https?:[a-zA-Z0-9./]+
```

If you update your question with better examples of the actual text you're trying to search in, I can improve my pattern as necessary.

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to pull URLs out of that mess programatically. Where did it come from? I think you'll have to do find them all manually.